# Handling small files with PIG

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

According to my understanding Map/Reduce works better with large files. ( I understand its due to splitting logic ,etc ), we can put files as values and file name as key in the sequence files and optimize.

Now the issue is I am using PIG for analytics, and we have around thousands of files but all are in KB. As we know pig latin is converted and run as MR jobs, so I've a doubt that MR jobs will be in-efficient owing to small files.

Is there any way by which I can get some control over small files handling over pig ? 
Is there any out of the box solution?

Comment: A few thousands of KB can easily fit in memory. Why do you want to use Hadoop/PIG for that ?

Comment: Thousands of files, each ~1000 KB may not fit in memory

Answer (score 2):

Pig has the feature of combining small files into bigger chunks:
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/perf.html#combine-files

Comment: Thanks Ruslan, this is something I was looking for :)